# Makefile doesn't rebuild objects on header modification

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, makefile

I have made a Makefile for compiling my C programm but it's not building object when i change one of the headers.

My MakeFile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-O3 -Wall
LDFLAGS=-I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=bin/beta_parser

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o:%.c types.h cstes.h headers.h mysql.h 
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean mrproper

clean:
    rm -rf *.o

mrproper:
    rm -rf $(EXEC)
```

What have I done wrong ?

EDIT : Corection of the Makeil after a great comment.

Comment: Probably an unrelated problem, but your rule for the executable is unwise.  You're specifying `beta_parser` as the target, but you're actually creating `bin/beta_parser`.  That will mean that rule gets run every time, unnecessarily.

Comment: thanks for this fix :-) But yes in fact this doesn't afect my other problem :-(

Comment: Typically your output should always be specified as `-o $@`, which will expand to whatever target make is building.

Comment: Unless you have a very specific reason for using Make, I would suggest going with CMake instead which provides you with more declarative and portable way of specifying what you want to build.

Comment: Yes but I don't have really the time to learn how to make a CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are other more elegant tricks, in your case, I think something like

```
$(OBJECTS): types.h cstes.h headers.h mysql.h

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: Great ! it's exactly what i was trying to do :-) Thank you a lot !

Comment: What is the rationale?  i.e. why does this behave differently?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I honestly have no clue. I encountered the same problem once and fixed it this way. I suppose make doesn't handle mixed (pattern and explicit) dependencies very well.

Comment: If I undertand it well, in the first case, make check the date of .o. They are file, not rules. In the seconde case, we make a rule for building explicitly all object with the headers dependences.
I thing that %.o:%.c is a "sugar" not a real gramarly corect statement.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin Yes, but make will translate that pattern rule to an explicit rule for every .o target it needs to build. So ideally, your way of doing it should also work.

Comment: Yes it should but i don't think he take care at all of any other element on the same line...

Answer (score 1):

Scanning your sources for dependencies is outside the scope of Make (although there are other tools, such as CMake which will do this automatically). You need to add an explicit rule to generate these dependencies, but this can be done in many different ways. I've sometimes used the following technique:

```
OBJECTS = ....
-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
...
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS) $< > $*.d
```

Google for "make automatic dependency generation" will show you other ways to do it as well.

Comment: Humm I think i will just rebuild all when a i change my header :-) But thanks for the answer !

Comment: Doing a full rebuild on a header change quickly becomes very time consuming as your project grows, and kind of defeats the purpose of using make at all. You could just do "gcc *.c -o myprog". :)

Comment: Yes i have a very litle program and the headers will not change a lot, so for this project it's a relative solution ;-)